# Write a predicate that tests if all elements of a numeric list are positive. @mndrix

Tags: prolog

how to write clauses, predicates and domains correctly?

```
all_greater_than_zero([]).
all_greater_than_zero([H|T]) :-
    H > 0,
    all_greater_than_zero(T).
```

Comment: I'm a new in Prolog and don't know how to do it

Comment: But this is correct.

Comment: This is a correct implementation. You can use `clpfd` in case the list of variables is not yet grounded for example.